# vue-cli service ignore typescript type errors on directory

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-cli

How can I configure the vue-cli tool to not run type checks on a specific folder?

- I spun up a new app with https://cli.vuejs.org
- I generated a jQuery/TypeScript API directory via codegen: `src/api/`
- I ignored in the tslint file the `"src/api/**/*.ts",`

Try to build, but the cli tool is also checking for type errors.

The output of serve is:

```
vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
Starting type checking and linting service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
 98% after emitting CopyPlugin                                                    

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 2701ms                                                                     3:50:28 PM

Type checking and linting in progress...

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.1.32:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.

ERROR in /home/me/code/g2/frontend/fe_main/src/api/ms-authentication/api/AuthenticationApi.ts
25:12 Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'JQueryAjaxSettings | undefined'.
    23 |     protected basePath = 'http://localhost';
    24 |     public defaultHeaders: Array<string> = [];
  > 25 |     public defaultExtraJQueryAjaxSettings?: JQueryAjaxSettings = null;
       |            ^
    26 |     public configuration: Configuration = new Configuration();
    27 | 
    28 |     constructor(basePath?: string, configuration?: Configuration, defaultExtraJQueryAjaxSettings?: JQueryAjaxSettings) {
ERROR in /home/me/code/g2/frontend/fe_main/src/api/ms-authentication/api/PasswordApi.ts
25:12 Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'JQueryAjaxSettings | undefined'.
    23 |     protected basePath = 'http://localhost';
    24 |     public defaultHeaders: Array<string> = [];
  > 25 |     public defaultExtraJQueryAjaxSettings?: JQueryAjaxSettings = null;
       |            ^
    26 |     public configuration: Configuration = new Configuration();
    27 | 
    28 |     constructor(basePath?: string, configuration?: Configuration, defaultExtraJQueryAjaxSettings?: JQueryAjaxSettings) {
```

But I cannot change this code without modifying the codegen templates. :/

Comment: As htn pointed out, those are build errors in TypeScript 2.0 (or later), where the [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) compiler option was introduced. If you need to include this code, you could disable `strictNullChecks` in `tsconfig.json` to workaround the build error, but you'd lose the strict check in your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either modify the generated code or disable the `strictNullChecks` of typescript compiler option.